# What is a healthy acceptance rate for Metropolis-Hastings algorithm?

Tags: markov-process, metropolis-hastings

I'm using Metropolis-Hastings algorithm to evaluate the posterior distribution of the parameters of a hierarchial Bayesian model. What is considered a healthy acceptance rate for the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm? Should the hyperparameters and parameters have the same acceptance rate? Or should they be different?

I particularly want to know whether there should be a difference in the acceptance rates of parameters and hyperparameters.

Comment: When you google the question, you will find plenty of answers, including some on this [forum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12155/7224).

Comment: Is there a difference in the acceptance rates of parameters and hyperparameters? The posted problem didn't answer that!

Comment: And some recommends 0.44. What is the difference in the assumption behind 0.44 and 0.234 acceptance rate?

Comment: The linked answer and the reference it gives discuss parameters; that will apply. However the paper operates under a set of assumptions / conditions that would make it more of a rough heuristic in general.