# Dynamically adjusting parameters of Markov chain

Tags: autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

I am using a [Metropolis algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) to generate samples from a complicated (high-dimensional) probability distribution. As is common, the proposed updates depend on some "step size" parameter $\epsilon$, such that

- too small $\epsilon$ leads to very small updates and thus long auto-correlations
- too large $\epsilon$ leads to small acceptance-rates and thus long auto-correlations.

Common wisdom is that one should choose $\epsilon$ such that the overall acceptance probability is somewhere in the 50%-90% range in order to optimize for autocorrelation times. Usually this tuning is done by hand, i.e. using a couple of trial runs.

No the question: **Is it valid to adjust $\epsilon$ dynamically during the Markov process? By "valid" I mean, is the stationary distribution of the process still the same?**

For example I could track the acceptance-rate so far, and:

- If the rate is $<0.9$, decrease $\epsilon$ a little
- If the rate is $>0.9$, increase $\epsilon$ a little

I could do this automatic adjustment after every step. I dont see why this would be wrong (after all, the stationary distribution does not depend on $\epsilon$). But it seems very fishy to me to make the simulation parameters dependent on the simulation results.

Could someone help me to wrap my head around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the acceptance rate for random walk Metropolis-Hastings and MALA should be lower than 50%. For instance, to quote from [an answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12162/7224) to an [earlier X validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12155/7224),

> I believe that [Weak convergence and optimal scaling of random walk
> Metropolis algorithms](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-7/issue-1/Weak-convergence-and-optimal-scaling-of-random-walk-Metropolis-algorithms/10.1214/aoap/1034625254.full) by Roberts, Gelman and Gilks is the source for
> the 0.234 optimal acceptance rate.
>
> What the paper shows is that, under certain assumptions, you can scale
> the random walk Metropolis-Hastings algorithm as the dimension of the
> space goes to infinity to get a limiting diffusion for each
> coordinate. In the limit, the diffusion can be seen as "most
> efficient" if the acceptance rate takes the value 0.234. Intuitively,
> it is a tradeoff between making to many small accepted steps and
> making to many large proposals that get rejected.

Second, to keep tuning $\varepsilon$ according to earlier runs invalidates the Markov justification of MCMC algorithms unless the tuning is controlled, for instance under diminishing adaptation. [Entries on X Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=adaptive%20metropolis) with the keywords `adaptive` and `metropolis` provide some references on the topic.

Comment: Hm. interesting point on the optimal acceptance rate. In my field of research (lattice qcd), rates over 90% are certainly very common (using "hybrid monte carlo" methods). Maybe I should investigate that^^. Anyway, I wasnt aware that "adaptive metropolis" is a thing. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Another "optimal" way to scale the random walk proposal is to aim at a variance that is twice the variance of the target (no matter what the dimension is).